# Dividir una imagen en 4 partes iguales utilizando php

Tags: php

Actualmente estoy intentando dividir una imagen en otras 4 imágenes del mismo tamaño a partir de la primera. El resultado que busco es que la altura de la imagen original se divida entre 4 y a partir de ahí obtener esas 4 posibles imágenes, empezando cada una donde acabaría la altura de la siguiente. Lo explico gráficamente para que podáis entenderlo mejor:

**Imagen original:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Resultado esperado**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código con el que he conseguido sacar el primer recorte:

```
    $filename= "imagen.png";
    list($w, $h, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($filename);
    $src_im = imagecreatefrompng($filename);

    $src_x = '0';
    $src_y = '0';
    $src_w = $w; // ancho
    $src_h = $h/4; // alto
    $dst_x = '0';
    $dst_y = '0';

    $dst_im = imagecreatetruecolor($src_w, $src_h);
    $white = imagecolorallocate($dst_im, 255, 255, 255);
    imagefill($dst_im, 0, 0, $white);

    imagecopy($dst_im, $src_im, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_x, $src_y, $src_w, $src_h);

    header("Content-type: image/png");
    imagepng($dst_im);
    print_r($dst_im);
```

¿Cual sería la mejor forma para conseguir guardar los 4 recortes?

> **Extra:** ¿Como podría hacer que el número de partes a recortar fuese X en vez de 4?

Comment: No te saldría más a cuenta descargar la imagen y editarla tú mismo? Entonces podrías recortar-las y poner-las en elementos separadas, podría tener un mejor juego.

Comment: Es un ejemplo simplificado, desde luego que sólo para lo que menciono en dicho ejemplo saldría más a cuento hacer lo que propones, pero en mi caso real la imagen se genera así y necesito cortarla con PHP. Sí no es obvio que no llegaría a plantearme todo esto, pero mi situación lo requiere. imagina por ejemplo que tuviese que descargar 200 imágenes y hacerlo a mano, ahí está la gracia de automatizarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partir de lo que tienes, te hace falta cambiar muy pocas cosas para conseguir lo que quieres. Ésta es una manera de hacerlo intentando modificar lo mínimo posible tu código:

- Pasar parámetros en el GET para poder seleccionar la imagen e indicar en cuántas partes quieres que se corte. Por ejemplo, la llamada a tu fichero PHP sería así:

  ```
  recortadorImagenes.php?pic=NOMBRE_DE_LA_IMAGEN&num=NUMERO_DE_IMAGENES
  ```
- Leer esos parámetros con PHP:

  ```
  $filename = $_GET["pic"];
  $number   = $_GET["num"];
  ```
- Calcular la altura de las nuevas imágenes recortadas (altura total de la imagen / número de imágenes en lugar de 4):

  ```
  $src_h = $h/$number;
  ```
- Crear un bucle en el que se crearán todas las sub-imágenes:

  ```
  for ($x = 0; $x < $number; $x++) {
  ```
- Cambiar el principio de donde se va a copiar la imagen al destino para que sea a partir de la posición que corresponda en el bucle:

  ```
  imagecopy($dst_im, $src_im, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_x, ($x * $src_h), $src_w, $src_h);
  ```
- Exportar la sub-imagen a un fichero en lugar de mostrarla por pantalla (que sería complicado al ser varias en lugar de una sola). Eso se consigue pasando un segundo parámetro a la función [imagepng](http://php.net/manual/es/function.imagepng.php), el nombre será único si usas el índice del bucle (ojo puede haber conflictos y se sobreescribiría el fichero, además debes asegurarte de que tienes permisos):

  ```
  imagepng($dst_im, str_replace(".png", "_$x.png", $filename));
  ```

  si la imagen se llama "imagen.png", entonces las sub-imágenes serán "imagen_0.png", "imagen_1.png", ....

Y aquí está el código que lo hace (con comentarios en las líneas que han cambiado):

```
<?php

    // leer los parámetros del GET
    $filename = $_GET["pic"];
    $number   = $_GET["num"];

    list($w, $h, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($filename);
    $src_im = imagecreatefrompng($filename);

    $src_x = '0';
    $src_y = '0';
    $src_w = $w; // ancho
    $src_h = $h/$number; // calcular el alto dependiendo del número de subimágenes
    $dst_x = '0';
    $dst_y = '0';

    // hacer un bucle para tantas imágenes
    for ($x = 0; $x < $number; $x++) {
        $dst_im = imagecreatetruecolor($src_w, $src_h);
        $white = imagecolorallocate($dst_im, 255, 255, 255);
        imagefill($dst_im, 0, 0, $white);

        // cambiar el principio de donde se copia a partir de la imagen que toque
        imagecopy($dst_im, $src_im, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_x, ($x * $src_h), $src_w, $src_h);

        // guardar como imagen en lugar de mostrar por pantalla
        imagepng($dst_im, str_replace(".png", "_$x.png", $filename));
    }
```